# How to hide tab placement in JTabbed pane?

Tags: java, swing, tabs, jtabbedpane

i am using JTabbedPane in my project. In this i can change the tab placement to TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT.Like,

```
 tabbedPane.setTabPlacement(JTabbedPane.BOTTOM);
 tabbedPane.setTabPlacement(JTabbedPane.TOP);
```

But i want to hide all tabs and just use like a normal panel by using Tabbed index id instead of showing that tab on my design. Is there any way to hide tab placement in java swing like,

```
 tabbedPane.setTabPlacement(null);
```

Comment: Sounds like you should be using [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) instead.

Comment: I'm currently working with a similar frame design, just use CardLayout as shown above by kiheru and add the `tabbedPanes`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to hide the tab placement:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabbedPane.getTabCount(); i++) {
    tabbedPane.setTabComponentAt(i, new JLabel());
}
```

[You're right it doesn't make disappear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaBCE.png)

Comment: I think maybe you misunderstood the question (or maybe I did). I believe that the OP wants the tabs (of the `JTabbedPane`) to not appear at all. Looks to me like your code simply displays an "empty" tab. Maybe you can [edit] your question and post a screen capture showing how the `JTabbedPane` looks when you run your code so as to verify whether it does not display tabs at all.